# Citing aligned siunitx entries in a tabular

Tags: biblatex, biber, siunitx

In the following MWE, how can I cite `siunitx` entries in a tabular when the entries are aligned using a specification such as `S[table-format=-2.3,table-number-alignment=right]`?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,articletitle=true,chaptertitle=true,refsection=chapter,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=99,doi=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{general.bib}
@ARTICLE{SaenzMendez2017,
  author = {Saenz-M{\'e}ndez, Patricia and Katz, Aline and P{\'e}rez-Kempner, Mar{\'\i}a Luc{\'\i}a and Ventura, Oscar N and V{\'a}zquez, Marta},
  title = {Structural insights into human microsomal epoxide hydrolase by combined homology modeling, molecular dynamics simulations, and molecular docking calculations},
  journal = {Proteins},
  year = {2017},
  volume = {85},
  pages = {720--730}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{general.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is a citation.\autocite{SaenzMendez2017}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=-2.3,table-number-alignment=right]
S[table-format=2.4,table-number-alignment=right]
}
    \toprule
    & {$T_m$ (\si{\celsius})} & {$\eta$ (\si{\milli\pascal})}\\
    \midrule
    A & 14(1) & 38(1)\\
    B & -85(2) & 104(4)\\
    \addlinespace
    C & -1.71(7) & 32.2(6)\\
    D & -2.93(4) & 50.09(90)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table 1 caption.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=-2.3,table-number-alignment=right]
S[table-format=2.4,table-number-alignment=right]
}
    \toprule
    & {$T_m$ (\si{\celsius})} & {$\eta$ (\si{\milli\pascal})}\\
    \midrule
    A & 14(1) & 38(1)\\
    B & -85(2)\autocite{SaenzMendez2017} & 104(4)\\
    \addlinespace
    C & -1.71(7) & 32.2(6)\\
    D & -2.93(4)\autocite{SaenzMendez2017} & 50.09(90)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table 2 caption.}
\end{table}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: If you use `table-format=-2.2(1),` instead of `table-format=-2.3,` for the first column (and analogously for the second column) then at least the second citation is comes directly after the number. The first citation is aligned with the second citation, so there is some space left after the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following MWE, I made these changes in comparison to the original code:

- I corrected the wrong `table-format` options. For the first column, you should use `-2.2(1)` to account for the uncertainty, for the second column, use `3.2(1)` to account for the uncertainty and the three digit number in the second row. (See also [my answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575788/134144))
- To add some space for the superscript number (otherwise you're left with a bunch of overfull box warnings), you can use `table-space-text-post={\textsuperscript{1}}`.
- With just these two changes/additions, the superscript numbers will now be aligned with respect to each other, as the first table show. If you prefer the numbers to be shown right next to their respective entry, you can add `table-align-text-post=false` as I did in the second table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,articletitle=true,chaptertitle=true,refsection=chapter,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=99,doi=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{general.bib}
@ARTICLE{SaenzMendez2017,
  author = {Saenz-M{\'e}ndez, Patricia and Katz, Aline and P{\'e}rez-Kempner, Mar{\'\i}a Luc{\'\i}a and Ventura, Oscar N and V{\'a}zquez, Marta},
  title = {Structural insights into human microsomal epoxide hydrolase by combined homology modeling, molecular dynamics simulations, and molecular docking calculations},
  journal = {Proteins},
  year = {2017},
  volume = {85},
  pages = {720--730}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{general.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is a citation.\autocite{SaenzMendez2017}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=-2.2(1),table-number-alignment=right, table-space-text-post={\textsuperscript{1}}]
S[table-format=3.2(2),table-number-alignment=right]
}
    \toprule
    & {$T_m$ (\si{\celsius})} & {$\eta$ (\si{\milli\pascal})}\\
    \midrule
    A & 14(1) & 38(1)\\
    B & -85(2)\autocite{SaenzMendez2017} & 104(4)\\
    \addlinespace
    C & -1.71(7) & 32.2(6)\\
    D & -2.93(4)\autocite{SaenzMendez2017} & 50.09(90)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table 2 caption.}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=-2.2(1),table-number-alignment=right,table-space-text-post={\textsuperscript{1}}, table-align-text-post=false]
S[table-format=3.2(2),table-number-alignment=right]
}
    \toprule
    & {$T_m$ (\si{\celsius})} & {$\eta$ (\si{\milli\pascal})}\\
    \midrule
    A & 14(1) & 38(1)\\
    B & -85(2)\autocite{SaenzMendez2017} & 104(4)\\
    \addlinespace
    C & -1.71(7) & 32.2(6)\\
    D & -2.93(4)\autocite{SaenzMendez2017} & 50.09(90)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table 2 caption.}
\end{table}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been working like mad on my thesis, and you really helped me out.